# Sharing temp variable between two same custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created custom directive and applied it two times on the same html page.
In the controller of the directive I have function that sets value of some **TEMP** variable. When I use let's say first directive and inside of it set value of this **TEMP** variable and after that when I use the second directive  value of **TEMP** variable is not available.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you need provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend having a `service` or `controller` (depending on whether a controller is applicable in this case) that sits above the directives. It can hold the base copy of the variable, and be read from or written to.

For example, in your directive:

```
localTemp = tempService.temp;
// or scope.temp if pulling scope from a controller like link: function (scope, elem, attr) {...}
...
tempService.temp = localTemp;
```

You may have to put this second line inside a `$timeout(...)` if you have this variable directly visible on your page in order for the change to be picked up by the Angular digest, propagated and displayed in your UI.

Comment: That's the awesome recommendation. It works. Thanks a lot @Rory